# Como otimizar essa consulta no MySQL que está muito lenta?

Tags: mysql, otimização, moodle

Estou fazendo uma consulta simples no LMS Moodle para pegar a quantidade de acessos de todos os usuários.

```
SELECT
    count(userid) as total,
    action,
    userid
FROM
    mdl_logstore_standard_log log
WHERE
    action = 'loggedin'
GROUP BY 
    userid
```

A tabela envolvida tem mais de 500 mil linhas e a tendência é só aumentar.

Rodei ela faz 4, 5 minutos e ainda não mostrou os resultados.

Não tem um jeito de fazer alguma otimização?

Meu conhecimento é limitado em Performance de Banco de Dados.

Comment: Adiciona um índice com o campo `action` desta forma: `ALTER TABLE mdl_logstore_standard_log ADD INDEX IAction (action);`

Comment: Coloque um [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) e diga nos qual é o retorno.

Comment: Retorna o nome das colunas, tipos...

Comment: Só mostra auto_incremente na chave primária. No resto das colunas está vazio.

Comment: @RobertoFagundes funcionou o Index.

Comment: Ok, vou colocar como resposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adicione um `INDEX` na sua tabela. Como o campo de filtro é o `action`, o seu `INDEX` deverá ter como referência este mesmo campo:

```
ALTER TABLE mdl_logstore_standard_log ADD INDEX IAction (action);
```

Caso queira aprofundar o conhecimento com os `INDEX` do `MySQL`, [clique aqui](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html).